# How do I find the last access time of a file in php

Tags: php, file, lastaccesstime

I need to know when the last time a file (main.html) was accessed using PHP. I want the user be able to see when the last time a different user accessed the page.
How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: use `fileatime` with a cost of performance for heavy traffic. (Some Unix file systems can be mounted with `atime` updates disabled to increase the performance). more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php

Comment: Bear in mind robots skew data.

Comment: I am going to mention that the PHP "documentation" is not very good, and I prefer not to use it if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function fileatime is used to get the last access time of the given file.

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "$filename was last accessed: " . date("F d Y H:i:s.", fileatime($filename));
    }

// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last accessed: December 29 2002 22:16:23.
```